# Wireshark - Filter for Inbound HTTP Requests on Port 80 Only

Tags: http, wireshark

We are integrating with an outside company in which we have had to make certain IP and port restrictions.

First, I am novice at network administration, so If I butcher anything, please forgive me.

I am using Wireshark to try to catch incoming traffic to my machine and came across a post that used the following filter expression:

```
(ip.dst_host == 192.168.20.155) || (ip.src_host == 192.168.20.155 && tcp.srcport == 80) && tcp
```

If I am checking for an inbound HTTP Post on Port 80...would this be sufficient? Furthermore, if I additionally wanted to check inbound HTTPS Posts on Port 443, how would I modify this?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 6):

You need to differentiate between capture filters and display filters. The syntax you're showing there is a Wireshark display filter. Display filters are used to filter out traffic from display but aren't used to filter out traffic during capture. You can learn more about Wireshark display filters [from the Wireshark wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters).

If you're going to be doing a long-term capture and you want to limit the size of your capture files you'll probably want to use a capture filter. Wireshark capture filters use tcpdump filter syntax, so [an article about tcpdump filters](http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/) will help you out.

To capture only HTTP traffic to/from the host 10.0.0.1, for example, you could use the capture filter `host 10.0.0.1 and tcp and port 80`. If you wanted that to include HTTPS traffic (TCP port 443) you could modify it to read  `host 10.0.0.1 and tcp and (port 80 or port 443)`.

For a display filter to do the same thing w/ HTTP only you'd be looking at `ip.addr == 10.0.0.1 && tcp.port == 80`. For both HTTP and HTTPS you'd be looking at `ip.addr == 10.0.0.1 && (tcp.port == 80 || tcp.port == 443)`.